# How do I check the version of PHP in my PHP Code

Tags: php

I am migrating to the latest 7.3 and would like to get in all the code before actually migrating. I need to use the function is_countable which is new to 7.3 so it will throw an error on my existing site running on 7.2. So, I created a function in the mean time is_countable_temp($temp) which just returns TRUE.

What I would like to do is check the version and if it is greater then or equal to 7.3 then use the actual is_counbable function else just return true.

```
enter code here

    function is_countable_temp($temp) {
       // if version is 7.3 or greater then call the is_countable function else just return true.
    }
```

Comment: check this: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.phpversion.php#112131

Answer (score 2):

You can get the php version like described [here](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.phpversion.php) and compare it with [version compare](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.version-compare.php):

```php
function is_countable_temp($temp) {
    return version_compare(phpversion(), '7.3', '>=') 
               ? is_countable($temp) 
               : true;
}
```

But you could also achieve the desired functionality with `function_exists('is_countable')`, so:

```php
function is_countable_temp($temp) {
    return function_exists('is_countable') 
               ? is_countable($temp) 
               : true;
}
```

And you are aware that we are at version 8 already, right?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (version_compare(phpversion(), '7.3', '>='))
{
       //do something
}
else
{
       return false;
}
```